# Flow and Ramda dynamic usage?

Tags: flowtype, ramda.js

I'm not sure where to report this or whether it could be something that can be fixed, but I think at least a simple case like this should be found by Flow.

```
const someComponent = (props: Props) =>
   const { children, doesntExist } = props; // Flow error here, great.
   const anotherOne = pick(['doesntExist'], props); // no error here
   // ...
```

Shouldn't it support this case? Is it a bug? Should be on ramda's or flow's contributors hands?

Comment: The [ramda documentation of `pick`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pick) says that if the property is not found, it is ignored. That is, the value of the key will be undefined if it doesn't exist in the original object. Since the API contract does not require that the property exists, I don't think Flow should raise an error.

Comment: Thing is, if prop doesn't exist both `doesntExist` and `anotherOne` are set to `undefined`, flow reports the first but doesn't the latter. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

[Original Flow type signatures look like this](https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/blob/efe6fe387a53c0b69209a962734bf9ba924c98f2/definitions/npm/ramda_v0.x.x/flow_v0.62.x-/ramda_v0.x.x.js#L1505-L1511):

```
declare function pick<A>(
  keys: Array<string>,
): (val: { [key: string]: A }) => { [key: string]: A };
declare function pick<A>(
  keys: Array<string>,
  val: { [key: string]: A }
): { [key: string]: A };
```

We can change it to

```
declare function pick <T>(
  keys: Array<$Keys<T>>,
  val: T
): $Shape<T>;
declare function pick <T>(
  keys: Array<$Keys<T>>
): (T) => $Shape<T>;
```

The result will be

```
type Props = {
  children: string,
  val: number,
}
const someComponent = (props: Props) => {
  const p1 = pick(['children1'], props); // Flow error here
  const p2 = pick(['children'], props);
  (p2: {children: string});
  // welp, but this is sad
  (p2: {val: number});
}
```

You can play with it in [Flow playground](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwAcswBreAHgBUA+ACgCh54SQBPAZwC54BBGGKK3IASANJt2VatQA0jeADcoEbpXoBKbsIDKACygEQUgNz1QkWAhTpseQsTJSGTFh258BQsRKnUN3Wkp1eABeangdfUMTenoMVkN4AAUYHAJ2UPgAb3kwXSwIYDhUbnYMGCxUAHM5JiUVeFRkAFsAIxAYOQBfejA8Mvh2HGaQAGFhgjwQVAxM2gJU9O4UtPZgsOzc-tmCAEZMolJaAG0AcjyCound04BdGUJFteN4AHpX+AAxCBwAd3gOqkYPBdB0QFtUAMCAAmA4OE7nfKFYp3B4LVbqUxMebQ7hZC7I6alcqVKpdTHyd7wX4gCAEB6tZCzDD5DJYDLsKDAeQ4vH1bhNNodcmmHpAA)

If TypeScript is an option check out [monocle-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/monocle-ts). [It provided Flow signatures some times ago, but dropped it](https://github.com/gcanti/monocle-ts/commit/dc299738f41576b20eab0aac8142a4fdcf3fb759), you can try resurrect it and put in flow-typed repo.

UPD: Maybe [idx](https://github.com/facebookincubator/idx) is what you are looking for

```
const p1 = idx(props, (_) => _.children1); // Flow error here
```

You can play with it in [Flow playground](https://flow.org/try/#0GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAJgDwDwBUYBpFYBuAfABQxgAOIUAXAXogIYQQCmAzh3AE73lUa9HAEpEAXmIFCI+gH4iiAN4AoRIig8AnsrXrEPNlBA8kLdl14DqUEQG49AX0QQmUCAAtEpNjx68xVX1kYG9ffx5kMA4oJkg2OFCsLUo2AFE-AN1g9UNjU0RwFDZgCjYUB2DHPXUoD38Ad0Rw3krEauqVKBS2RAAFf0oOCWyXDxgAGxRDMHoYngoAc1w9QiYJ+jAQAFsAI18V6ogEGMRubbYAYThtygQ2MCgR0kpBjnoBuCGxSVHj6KelAAjCNUGgXm98KQAPo-KTQgB0nkm0weQPsiAA9JjEAAxCZwJotSIeXxsPT-U6UABMoPQEK+HChsIk8KR4ymM3sehe1Pk8yW3OqQA)